# jQuery condition for stop setInterval polling

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, asynchronous, setinterval

I have the following jQuery code:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
             setInterval(function() {
                $.get('async', function(data) {
                    $('#datum').text(data);          
                } );     
             }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

        });  
    </script>
```

In which case I present back a String result from a servlet called async using the following html:

The String either contains the word running, or completed. I want to stop the polling in the above if the data variable contains "completed".  I have tried the following code snipplet but I am confused exactly where to place it, or if it is even correct:

```
    if (data ==="completed") {
            for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {window.clearInterval(i);}
    }
```

I have also tried

```
if ( $('#datum').text(data) ==="completed" ) { 
  for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {window.clearInterval(i);} 
}
```

I have made multiple attempts, all of which break the functionality. Without attempting to stop polling, the above works perfectly fine to constantly poll and return the status "running", except when it reaches "completed" it continues polling as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the return value of the `setInterval` call (which is the ID of the interval) in order to clear the interval later on. Example:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
             var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                $.get('async', function(data) {
                    $('#datum').text(data);
                    if(data === 'completed'){
                      clearInterval(intervalID);
                    }          
                } );     
             }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

        });  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` function returns the ID of the interval. You need to clear the interval with that ID if you want to stop polling. Your snippet looks whether data equals "completed" and not whether it contains "completed". Use the `indexOf` function instead of `===`. The snippet should be where you know the value of data and want to parse it.